# Test if a given point q is a kernel of polygon P

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

> Point $q$ is a kernel of a polygon $P$ if from $q$ we can see all vertices of $P$.
>
> In addition, kernel is a intersection of $N$ half planes formed by edges of polygon.

Proofs of the above statements can be found in [Visibility and Kernel of Polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142213/visibility-and-kernel-of-polygon).

I try to figure out what the efficient way of testing if point $q$ is kernel or not.

The most naive way is to construct intersection of $N$ half spaces of polygon $P$, it should take $O(nlogn)$ and then check if point $q$ belongs to intersection of half spaces. So, all this process should take $O(nlogn)$.

I assume that more efficient way should exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intersection of the halfspaces can in fact be computed in linear time, $O(n)$,
by carefully exploiting the ordering provided by the polygon's boundary.
This is established in a 1979 paper by Lee & Preparata, "An Optimal Algorithm for Finding the Kernel of a Polygon"
([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322142)).

Once you have the kernel as a convex polygon, it is straightforward to check if $q$ lies inside it in time proportional the the number of edges $k \le n$ of the kernel.

Comment: thanks you very much for the paper!